# How often is PSS value updated for a given process in /proc/pid/smaps

Tags: linux, kernel, process, memory, virtual-memory

So if n processes are sharing a library L with size M then the contribution to their PSS is M/n.

Now imagine one of the process terminates. So the contribution would be M/(n-1).

Q1: My question is how soon is this change reflected in the PSS values of processes still running and using the shared library?

Q2: As a trivial case suppose only two processes are using a shared lib L of size 100K. PSS contribution to each process is 50K. Now when P2 dies it is the only process using L. So its PSS should increase and become 100K. How soon will this happen, as soon as P2 dies, or after some time? After how much time?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The change is reflected immediately. There is no caching along the way. When you read `/proc/<pid>/smaps`, you actually trigger a traversal of that process's page table. Information about the mappings is accumulated along the way, then displayed, without any caching.

The code behind the `/proc/<pid>/smaps` file is in `fs/proc/task_mmu.c`, specifically the [`show_smap`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=show_smap) function.
That function does a `walk_page_range` with [`smaps_pte_range`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=smaps_pte_range) as the PTE callback. `smaps_pte_range` itself accumulates the information in a `struct mem_size_stats`.

The part of that code responsible for `PSS` does:

```
mapcount = page_mapcount(page);
if (mapcount >= 2) {
    if (pte_dirty(ptent) || PageDirty(page))
        mss->shared_dirty += ptent_size;
    else
        mss->shared_clean += ptent_size;
    mss->pss += (ptent_size << PSS_SHIFT) / mapcount;
} else {
    if (pte_dirty(ptent) || PageDirty(page))
        mss->private_dirty += ptent_size;
    else
        mss->private_clean += ptent_size;
    mss->pss += (ptent_size << PSS_SHIFT);
}
```

(You can see here that pages can only be accounted in the `Shared` part if it is actually mapped more than once - it's accounted as private otherwise.)

[`page_mapcount`](http://lxr.free-electrons.com/ident?i=page_mapcount) is defined inline in `linux/mm.h` and simply accesses a `struct page`:

```
static inline int page_mapcount(struct page *page)
{
    return atomic_read(&(page)->_mapcount) + 1;
}
```

So PSS is "always up to date".